# Speed up SQL simple Query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, query-optimization

We have a table called PROTOKOLL, with the following definition:

[PROTOKOLL TableDefinition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Vkf.png)
The table has 10 million pcs of records.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ a.*, ROWNUM rnum  
          FROM (SELECT t0.*, t1.*
                   FROM PROTOKOLL t0
                      , PROTOKOLL t1 
           WHERE (
                  (
                    (t0.BENUTZER_ID = 'A07BU0006')
                      AND (t0.TYP = 'E')
                   ) AND 
                  (
                    (t1.UUID = t0.ANDERES_PROTOKOLL_UUID) 
                      AND 
                    (t1.TYP = 'A')
                  )
                 ) 
            ORDER BY t0.ZEITPUNKT DESC
                ) a 
          WHERE ROWNUM <= 4999) WHERE rnum > 0;
```

So practically we join the table with itself through ANDERES_PROTOKOLL_UUID field, we apply simple filterings. The results are sorted with creation time and the number of the result record set is limited to 5000.

The elapsed time of the query is about 10 Minutes! --- which is not acceptable ☹

I already have the execution plan and statistic information in place and trying to figure out how to speed up the query, pls. find them attached.

[image: ExecutionPlan]
[image: Statistics]

My first recognition, that the optimizer puts “"P"."ANDERES_PROTOKOLL_UUID" IS NOT NULL” condition additionally to the where clause, but I do not know why. Is it a problem?

Or where are the bottleneck of the query?

How can I avoid….Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Queries start with `select`, not `from`, so it is unclear what your query really is.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the query. It's correct format is:
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS */ a.*, ROWNUM rnum  
FROM (SELECT 
t0.*, t1.*
FROM PROTOKOLL t0, PROTOKOLL t1 
WHERE (((t0.BENUTZER_ID = 'A07BU0006') AND (t0.TYP = 'E')) AND ((t1.UUID = t0.ANDERES_PROTOKOLL_UUID) AND (t1.TYP = 'A'))) 
ORDER BY t0.ZEITPUNKT DESC) a WHERE ROWNUM <= 4999) WHERE rnum > 0;

Comment: As the author of the question, you can edit it directly rather than using a comment.